# edit docker container files with OS X Sublime Text

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, docker

Just started using docker on OS X for development. `vim`is convenient but I want to get back to Sublime Text 2.

**How do I fire up Sublime Text 2 on OS X and have it edit the files on my docker container?**

Using latest docker ver 1.0 on OS X. VM installed via `boot2docker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Docker 1.3 supports shared folders as per my original question:

https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/

Answer (score 1):

Currently boot2docker image doesn't support share folders. You can download [boot2docker-v1.0.0-virtualbox-guest-additions](http://static.dockerfiles.io/boot2docker-v1.0.0-virtualbox-guest-additions-v4.3.12.iso) and save it to `~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso`.

Longer article about how it works: [boot2docker together with VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c).